# How to handle dynamic images with Next

Tags: image, next.js, static-content

Next.js documentation says:
"Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage."

I have issue to understand how would you work with a site with dynamic content. I mean, let say i operate a merchant site, do i have to rebuild the site each time i add a product? or must i use a cdn for my images.

Sounds it should have a more easy way no?

Comment: As mentioned in their docs, the recommended way is to host/persist the files on a third-party service. However, you may want to have a look at this GH issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12656 which might shed some light on alternatives/workarounds.

Comment: This is hard, but not impossible. Because you have to declare your source domain in a next.config.js file, I thought that this meant you'd be back to building every time you added a new graphic, but I now realise it's just the **domain** you're declaring, so no prob if all your files come from the same domain. Now just got to sort out the sizing - nightmare!